# Adding a android license AFTER an initial release?

Tags: android

I originally didn't use the licensing service with my app.  It has been released for 4 months.  Now I am adding it.  Will this cause problems with those who have already bought it?

Also, Is there a way to remove a individual device license?

Thanks for any answers to these two questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have both added and removed the licence check for my applications and I had no negative reports from my users. So no, most likely there will be no problems for your users.

For the 2nd question: No, you can't remove a licence from a normal device. Also note that the licence is attached to the user not the device.

Only for your testing devices / users you can add and remove licences as you like.